# Https Post : MalformedURLException on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, url, http-post

When I am sending POST request to an url with authentication from GAE, I am getting MalformedURLException on urlConn.getResponseCode() function.

This problem arises only on the deployment server and does not arise when I run the code on local server.

```
Invalid URL specified: https://user:passtoken@twilix.exotel.in/v1/Accounts/user/Sms/send
java.net.MalformedURLException: Invalid URL specified: https://user:passtoken@twilix.exotel.in/v1/Accounts/user/Sms/send

at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:120)
at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:43)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:417)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getInputStream(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:296)
```

My code:

```
String urlString = 
      "https://user:passtoken@twilix.exotel.in/v1/Accounts/user/Sms/send";
URL url = new URL(urlString.toString());
String userpass = "user:passtoken";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + 
    javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());

urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
urlConn.connect();
responseCode = urlConn.getResponseCode();    //Throws Exception
```

Everything works fine when I try to set my url as https://httpbin.org/post

Is this a bug of GAE or some problem with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the ampersand symbol.  Since you are already putting the credentials in the HTTP Request, they should not be needed in the URL as well.  Try changing the first line to this instead.

```
String urlString = "https://twilix.exotel.in/v1/Accounts/user/Sms/send";
```